# Is it possible to make a window always on top of another window only?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

In WPF is it possible to make a Window "Always on top" of another external process window?

Suppose I would want my application to show always over the "notepad.exe" window only?

Comment: What if there are another application which want to be "Always on top" also? ;)

Comment: You can't win the always on top fight if the other app is not something you control. I suggest you consider whether setting topmost true then false is sufficient for your needs. And no. That's not going to make it stay on top of notepad. Not unless you get the source to notepad and make your window a child window. You could work out where your window is and then work out all other windows and decide to set topmost. But then some other app can also do that.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) function. In C#, you can implement a wrapper as such:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

You can learn more on [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) about the supported parameters that you can pass - you will need to reliably identify the window handle for the process, and then overlay the window.

Comment: This is not going to do what the OP wants. You can use the `SetWindowPos()` function to make a window "top-most" (always on top of _every_ window, except of course all those other ones that also made themselves "top-most" but after yours did), and you can use it to momentarily position your window in z-order above another one (e.g. the notepad.exe window). But you can't cause your _"application to show always over the "notepad.exe" window only"_ this way, i.e. to ensure that even if the user clicks on the notepad.exe window, your window stays on top of it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are correct, hence the "reliably identify the window handle for the process" part. Non-zero amount of effort to always figure out where to overlay.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Identifying the window handle is the easy part. The word "overlay" doesn't show up in the `SetWindowPos()` documentation page at all. None of that statement in your answer does anything to help the OP achieve their goal.

Comment: If the developer wants, they can build some logic that detects where in the stack the Notepad window is, and set the window position to be on top of that. Off top of my head, you could probably use `GetWindow` to identify the Z-order of the target window and act accordingly.

Comment: _"logic that detects where in the stack the Notepad window is"_ -- that's not the point, nor is that necessary. Having found the notepad.exe window handle (which is easy), they simply need to pass that as `hWndInsertAfter` to `SetWindowPos()`. The problem is that that's just a one-time thing. As soon as the user clicks on the notepad.exe window, it be brought forward, ahead of the other program's window. All that stuff you're talking about with respect to examining the existing z-order is irrelevant. It's not needed, and doing it doesn't help in any way to make the z-order change permanent.

Comment: Implementation details aside, you could in theory build a service that runs on a continuous basis and does exactly what the scenario is asking.

Comment: Uh, so: your proposal is to run continuously, repeatedly setting the window z-order over and over, indefinitely? As a user, I would unceremoniously and with prejudice delete any software I discovered on my computer that was doing anything so ridiculous.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this is not a question of whether you would use the software, but rather whether it is possible at all. Which it is 